# Random file from a folder inside JAR

Tags: java, executable-jar

I want to get a random image from a specific folder in Java. The code does already work inside the Eclipse IDE, but not in my runnable JAR. Since images inside the JAR file are not files, the code below results in a NullPointerException, but I'm not sure how to "translate" the code so that it will work in a runnable JAR.

```
final File dir = new File("images/");
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
Random rand = new Random();
File file = files[rand.nextInt(files.length)];
```

Comment: One of the "better" solutions would be to generate a file which contained all the image names in it.  You'd then load this file at run time, randomly select a name from it and pull that out of your Jar.  This "index" file should reside in your Jar file, along with the images

Comment: @someLongNumber Did you verified the Path inside JAR, for image directory. maybe this is a Path issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the given path is invalid then `listFiles()` method reutrns `null` value. So you have to handle it if the path is invalid. Check below code:

```
    final File dir = new File("images/");
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    Random rand = new Random();
    File file = null;
    if (files != null) {
        file = files[rand.nextInt(files.length)];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the jar is to contain the images then (assuming a maven or gradle project) they should be in the resources directory (or a subdirectory thereof). These images are then indeed no 'Files' but 'Resources' and should be loaded using `getClass().getResource(String name)` or `getClass.getResourceAsStream(String name)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a text file listing the resource paths of the images. This would allow you to simply read all lines from that file and access the resource via `Class.getResource`.

You could even create such a list automatically. The following works for my project type in eclipse; some minor adjustments may be needed for your IDE.

```
private static void writeResourceCatalog(Path resourcePath, Path targetFile) throws IOException {
    URI uri = resourcePath.toUri();
    try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(targetFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        Files.list(resourcePath.resolve("images")).filter(Files::isRegularFile).forEach(p -> {
            try {
                writer.append('/').append(uri.relativize(p.toUri()).toString()).append('\n');
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
writeResourceCatalog(Paths.get("src", "main", "resources"), Paths.get("src", "main", "resources", "catalog.txt"));
```

After building the jar with the new file included you could simply list all the files as

```
List<URL> urls = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(WriteTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/catalog.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
    String s;
    while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        urls.add(SomeType.class.getResource(s));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It seem like a path Problem, maybe will work if tried absolute path for image directory or set maon directory for java configuration